# Is there a node.js package for web scraping that will capture content outside of page source-code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

Some sites don't have everything in the page source code, you can only see the new elements when you load the page on a browser. I don't know why is that, I'm thinking maybe it's because a site requires javascript to be enabled? In python, I fixed my issue with the "AsyncHTMLSession" module and this code:

```
r = await session.get(url)
await r.html.arender()
```

It let me grab the new elements and do whatever I needed, is there anything like this for node.js?

Comment: if you want a browser, use a browser. And if you want to use a browser through node, use a headless browser solution. There's quite a lot of options (playwright, selenium, phantom, cypress, puppeteer, etc. etc.)

Comment: It's not really about using a browser (I would prefer not to), it's about something the browsers apparently have that the node.js packages like node-fetch, axios etc don't have and because of that can't load the content that I need to grab for my code.

Comment: If you want to replicate browser action instead of just doing a get request for the page html, you would be essentially rebuilding a browser. If you want to get browser action, I would recommend puppeteer. If there is a specific item which you can not find how to fetch without a browser, we would need more information to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You want the behaviour of a browser. So use a browser. You clearly don't want fetch, or get, or curl, you want "actually load the page, and run its scripts, to make it do what it does in a browser". I'd recommend Playwright, but any of the other options I already listed will do, and you shouldn't care about "what it actually uses", you should care about what it does for you. If it does what you need: that's what you needed.

Comment: Puppeteer for some reason is very slow, too slow for me (it takes like 2 min to load the page and do whatever lol) but I'll try Playwright

Answer (score 1):

Yes, basically you are looking for a way to access content that shows up when a page loads using JavaScript.

The solution you want is a headless browser - puppeteer does this very well.

Checkout: https://www.toptal.com/puppeteer/headless-browser-puppeteer-tutorial

Or even a quick video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXjKh66BR2U

Comment: It definitely makes sense, in python it was easier tho and I didn't need a browser. Puppeteer is sooo slow, I have no idea why but it takes like 2-3 min to load page and do the job